# How to use where clause to compare 2 columns in mongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How many products have discount % greater than 30%?
On pymongo (MongoDB driver library for Python),
I have

- `original_price` [store as float] and
- `sale_price` [store as float]

in mongoDB, I am using:

```py
# question 10:-How many products have discount % greater than 30%?
count=0
for x in db.leclerc_fr.find():
    if((x['sale_price']/x['original_price']<.7)):
        print(x)
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo field A greater than field B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042315/mongo-field-a-greater-than-field-b) combined with `.length()` maybe

Comment: Do you have to use `where`, or could you use an aggregation pipeline?